# Fix x_axis and fill under curve Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to configure my Bokeh plots in Python such that they look a bit nicer. For example, is there a way to fix the maximum zoom out? Such that Bokeh cannot zoom out more than what is specified by the x-axis? E.g. look at [bokeh example](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#datetime-axes), and especially "Datetime axes". I would like to fix the axis size so that you cannot zoom out more than the initial x axis is wide.

Another question; is there a way to fill an area under a curve in a specified color? Like in the figure [USDSEK](https://www.avanza.se/index/om-indexet.html/19000/usd-sek). I can provide code, but I don't think it's necessary for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATED for 2019:*

Bokeh now supports ["directed areas"](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#directed-areas) (which can also be stacked) see e.g.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_area.html

Comment: Thanks, this was my solution as well (got it to look exactly the same way as the link I provided).